# First accordion panel out of alignment with others in row

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap Accordion for a page with many products. I have 11 panels in 3 columns. When the window is sized to show all 3 columns the first panel is out of vertical alignment with the others in the first row. All other panels in rows below are in alignment.

Link to [Screenshot](http://[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/zjjlgn.jpg[/IMG])

There is a lot of code so I have given a link to it as I don't know how much to insert into a post.

[Link to code in JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/capabo/1/)

I am very new to this & don't understand how it works. I have searched for answers but cannot find anything for this specific issue, so would be grateful for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
 #accordion .panel:nth-of-type(1){
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Bootstrap doesn't add any margin to first element of panel. You need to add this in your case.

Comment: I have added `.panelgroup .panel{
  margin-top: 5px;
}` to my stylesheet which appears in the header after the bootstrap one.  but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
.panelgroup .panel{ margin-top: 5px !important; }
```

Comment: I've added `!important` to the declaration but still no difference.

Comment: in which browser the issue occurs ?

Comment: Chrome, Safari, FireFox, Opera & I.E.

Comment: Yes, it was a basic error. I copied the CSS suggestion exactly but the comma between `.panelgroup` and `.panel` was missing. It now works perfectly. Should I mark first suggestion as the answer even with the missing comma?